# Изменение текста UILabel через ViewController.m

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Я создал проект XCode для iOS, использую StoryBoard. У меня на данный момент 2 экрана. 
Контроллеры:
1) ViewController
2) SecondViewController

Вот Label которую я хочу редактировать, она находится в SecondViewController.h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
```

Как мне через контроллер первого экрана(ViewController.m) изменить значение переменной statusLabel. Можете просто подсказать как ее вызвать, чтоб была в зоне видимости.(Import уже сделал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во ViewController перед тем как перейти на второй контроллер создаете instance и вызываете statusLabel. Наверное Вы используете segue?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Имя segue"])
    {
        SecondViewController  *secondViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        secondViewController.statusLabel.text = @"Нужный текст";

    }
}
```

Comment: что такое segue?

Comment: Если работаете со StoryBoard настоятельно рекомендую почитать о них, например вот [тут][1]

[1]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/131128/